# Does intake mass-flow rate vary linear proportional with turbine fan speed?

Tags: jet-engine, inlet

Is jet turbine intake mass-flow rate linear proportional with its fan speed (N1)?

Comment: Or is maybe more linear related to fuel consumption rate, or thrust?

Comment: Is this a homework question? It kind of sounds like one.

Comment: Mass flow and thrust are closely related, and we have answered how thrust depends on engine speed [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/what-is-the-relationship-between-thrust-and-engine-rpm-in-a-turbojet). The short answer is No.

Comment: No its not homework.
Thank you, @PeterKämpf

Comment: Oops, I meant fan speed, so N1, editing the question.

Comment: Could you explain what N1 is, for lay readers?

Comment: Done now @daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not linear, because the back side of N1 will influence the flow. Not only that but the flow is non linear with respect to rotation in most axial flow compressors.

Is there a specific engine or cycle that you are wondering about, because that changes the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, the engine is Volvo RM8. I am simulating it, and have some info on it when its running, I need to find something that is linear or close to that with regards to the intake mass flow. I have thrust, fuel consumption, N1 and N2.

Comment: Then I would stick by the non linear model, as it is a two spool turbine.  If you can't get good data form airframe applications, that was used for ship propulsion, and you might get data that way. Remember that N1 is quadratic to thrust.

Comment: You might look up a paper by T Abbott of Langley (1990) on engine monitoring.

Comment: Many thanks @mongo.